# CLion: Split one long comment into multiple lines with fixed number of characters

Tags: ide, editor, clion

Is there any way to force comments to span multiple lines in a CMakeLists.txt and cpp files?

NOT

```
# So that really long comments that would not normally be split across multiple lines like this one, which look really annoying in git commit history or other editors which do not text wrap like the one on stack overflow . . . .
```

BUT

```
# So that really long comments
# end up split across multiple 
# lines like this?
```

In the Edit menu, there is a command to `join lines`. I effectively want the inverse of this function, so that the comments wrap at the thin vertical line displayed in the editor showing max width.

Comment: Just use C++ comments `//`: you'll see that it works as expected when hitting the <Enter> key

Comment: I want to paste a long bit of text from the internet into a CMakeLists.txt. The comment char is `#`

Comment: My bad: indeed this does not work in CMakeLists.txt. Maybe file a bug in youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/CPP

Comment: Even in a cpp file it does not wrap the comment correctly. I don't want to hit `<Enter>` to manually break a line up. This is dumb computer work

Answer (score 1):

Soft Wrapping does this for you.

on OSX
CLION -> Preferences -> Editor -> General -> Check Use soft wraps in editor.